# -たん (-tan) suffix (honorific) meaning?

Tags: honorifics

Came across the honorific -たん in Re:Zero (episode 4, 6 minutes in):

> You saved me, didn't you, Emilia-tan?

**Does anyone know what it means?**

The protagonist who said it clearly likes the female lead he addressed, but he also doesn't believe that anything is real. When she asks him what it means, he says:

> Uh, you can just ignore that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-たん is a lisped version of -ちゃん. It's probably the most cute-sounding, casual name suffix in Japanese. There are many fictional (usually female) characters who are always called with -たん.

- [OS-tan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS-tan) (oh, this article has [an explanation for -tan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS-tan#Tan_suffix), too)
- [Binchō-tan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binch%C5%8D-tan_(manga))

You should never use -たん in business settings even though it may be grammatically classified as an "honorific suffix".

Calling someone with -たん is one of the ways to show one's sense of intimacy/affection toward someone (like "honey" or "sweetie" in English), or to tease someone as if she were a child.